# Why is our site badge “UAV”?

Tags: discussion, bug

Usually betas have blue site badges with the first letters of their site title in the badge, for example: IPS: Interpersonal Skills

Why is our site badge UAV:

[image: badge]

Shouldn’t it be **DMA**?

Comment: Why not DAM (**D**rones **A**nd **M**odel aircraft)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it certainly breaks the pattern, I think it's a good thing we have `UAV` and not `DMA`.

To me, `UAV` more accurately summarizes what we're discussing here. `DMA` reminds me of [other stuff](https://www.acronymfinder.com/DMA.html) like the computer architecture/programming term [Direct Memory Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access).

Comment: What does “UAV” stand for though?

Comment: Unmanned Aerial Vehicle

Comment: UAV makes total sense, did you suggest this @ifconfig or did the StackExchange employees just come up with it themselves?

Comment: No, this was the work of SE staff. All I supplied was the name "Drones and Model Aircraft" when I made the site proposal.

Comment: @user1271772 It is something that Robert put in his recommendation when he reviewed the proposal back in December. He always dug into every proposal he reviewed to give it that special touch.

Comment: @animuson thank you very much for the clarity :)

Answer (score 4):

Several Beta sites have letters in their logo that don't readily fit the name. [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/) has "art" as its logo.

UAV is something many people will recognize as being relevant to the topic.